# How to control placement of asymmetric image masks in Google Sheets or Drawings

Tags: google-sheets, google-drawings

Google Sheets and Drawings allow the use of vector masks over images from any of their standard vector shapes. Some of these shapes are asymmetric, but I cannot figure out how to change the orientation of an asymmetric mask.

As an example, say I have the following image in Google Drawings:

[image: original]

I can apply an asymmetric image mask and get the following output:

[image: cropped]

But as far as I can tell, there's no way for the cut out sections to be on the bottom. If I try flipping the image, the crop gets flipped with it, and I get:

[image: inverted cropped]

Is there any way to do what I want, or is this simply unsupported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, select the mask (not the image), grab the little dot on a stalk and drag it round half a circle:

[image: WA65719 example]

Comment: I wasn't able to do it exactly as you described. Grabbing the "dot on a stalk" only succeeded in rotating the image with the mask. However, double clicking in the image brought up the crop UI (dark grey lines around the image), and dragging the "dot on a stalk" from here rotated the image independently of the the mask. So to do what you have illustrated, I would have to rotate the image 180 degrees independent of the mask, and then rotate the whole image back. Still worked though!